# template routes and category groups + categories

Tags: template-routes

I am in the process of setting up the structure of a new EE site and I've run into questions about routes and if this is possible or if I'm missing something. I apologize if this seems super simple, I've been through the docs and as many "template routes" search results as possible but I'm still not figuring this out.

Here is the current setup. I tried originally to do this originally with one single category group and multiple parent/child categories but it wasn't working. I'm not against that solution if that is what is necessary to achieve the desired results.

---

**One Channel** - Directory
4 Category Groups - Cat / Dog / Fish / Reptiles

**Listing Page** - list of posts with pagination
/directory/

**Category Group Page** - list of posts in a specific category group with pagination
/directory/cat/
/directory/cat/P1
/directory/dog/
/directory/dog/P1
etc.

**Category Pages** - list of posts in a specific category with pagination
/directory/cat/food
/directory/cat/food/P1
/directory/dog/food
/directory/dog/food/P1
etc.

**Single Page** - single entry 
/directory/category_group/url_title 
/directory/dog/barkbox-dog-review

**Template group:** 
Listing

**Templates & Routes:** 
directory-index | ROUTE: /directory/dog/{page:pagination}
directory-single | ROUTE: /directory/dog/{post:alpha_dash}/
directory-cat | ROUTE: /directory/dog/category/{section:alpha_dash}/{page:pagination}  (I had to add /category/ into this route, which I'd rather not have to do)

---

After a lot of back and forth, I got the above to work and then of course, I realized I was using a category group name (dog) in each route, which doesn't allow this to be dynamic. I would have to then create 3 templates per category group, which doesn't seem right.  I didn't even want 3 templates let alone 3 per category group.

Thank you for taking the time to read this and offering any help.

Comment: I could just make a template group /directory/ and be done with this. I just have numerous "listing" channels like this and wanted to keep things as trim as possible.

Comment: I'm awful with Structure (even though I maintenance a 10K-page site built on it) but I can possibly look into your issues tomorrow morning. If I don't respond, feel free to comment back so I get a notification. I'm a busy person but I love the forums.

Comment: Hey thanks. I ended up going in another direction and skipped the template routes. Thanks for looking though.